# conduct vs undertake vs pursue vs carry out

Tags: meaning, differences

I don't see any difference in meaning of these four. Can anyone explain me like I'm 5.

> conduct a study
>
> undertake a review
>
> pursue a policy
>
> carry out a research

In Russian we'd use one word in all these sentences. And the sense of it looks the same to me as well.

---

UPD: I think it'd be easier to figure it out using one activity, e.g. `review`:

> conduct a review
>
> undertake a review
>
> pursue a review
>
> carry out a review

Comment: In my opinion (no sources), the words aren't usually interchangeable. A catch-all word that could almost replace any of those verb phrases is "do", and that would have a general meaning of accomplishing the referenced object ("do a study", "do a review", etc). The purpose of the existing verb phrases is a suggestion about how those things are done: (1) "conduct" suggests leadership, (2) "undertake" suggests some amount of burden, (3) "pursue" suggests imperfection, and (4) "carry out" suggests continuance.

Comment: @lirmont it sounds rather intelligently. it should be an answer. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Conduct" and "carry out" seem synonymous in this context. Conduct specifically also has an "organizing the thing" connotation, where "carry out" specifically means the act of doing the thing.

Pursue has a chasing or demanding connotation, or at least a "following a current path, often over the long term" one ("pursue a degree in microbiology", for instance, makes sense). "*Pursue* a review" makes sense, but it has a different connotation in my eyes than "*undertaking*" one; again, because of the chasing/demanding connotation. The example that comes to mind is "somebody messed up, and now the entity pursuing a review is demanding that person's actions be gone over very carefully". "Pursue a study" makes *grammatical* sense, but I'm not sure in what concrete way it would make sense to chase after a study.

Then there's the diverging meanings these words can have outside these sample sentences, which color the other uses of the words. "Conduct" can also mean "behave in a specified way", as in "conduct yourself appropriately", in my experience a phrase used exclusively to refer to good manners and etiquette. In the way you're using it here, as a verb, the emphasis is also on the second syllable; "CON-duct", the noun, has a more primary association with manners and etiquette, and a secondary general sense of "the way someone does something".

"Undertake" apparently has a commitment/promise connotation, but its place on the list for me is "uncommon word that is apparently loosely synonymous with the other three, but mostly it makes me think of undertakers, AKA morticians AKA people who work with dead bodies".

Pursue has that chasing connotation, either in a straightforward "chase them and catch them" way, or as a euphemism for trying to get into a sexual or romantic relationship with someone. Its meaning is more "chasing a goal/thing, may or may not 'catch'/complete it", whereas "conduct" and "carry out" are more "have caught, now doing things to it, may or may not succeed in the doing".

"To carry out" research/a project/a study/a review all make sense in the same way; it's to do the thing or cause it to be done. To carry out a policy has a different meaning than to pursue it, though. If you're pursuing a policy, the connotation as I understand it is that the policy isn't a law/rule yet; if you're *carrying out* a policy, that has about the same meaning as to *enforce* a policy.

All but "pursue a policy" also have the same meaning, stated more informally, if you replace the verb with "to do"; "do a study, do a review, do research". A policy isn't something one *does*, though; policies are more abstract things than the other three.

That's about all the analyzing of these words I can manage for the moment without blatantly repeating myself. If there's a specific thing I didn't explain well enough, or I was using more specialized words that you'd like defined, I'll happily answer followup questions.

Comment: Wow, it's quite exhaustive. Thanks! Let's wait for other answers then I'll pick the best one.

Comment: And what about "perform"?